# How to test component that uses custom hook with React-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a custom hook to make async calls with setting errors, loadings etc.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useMakeAsyncCall = ({ asyncFunctionToRun = null, runOnMount = false }) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await asyncFunctionToRun();
      const json = await res.json();

      setResponse(json);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (runOnMount && asyncFunctionToRun !== null) fetchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [runOnMount]);

  return { response, error, loading, fetchData };
};

export default useMakeAsyncCall;
```

In component I am using it like this

```
const { error, isLoading, fetchData } = useMakeAsyncCall({
    asyncFunctionToRun: () => signUpUser(),
    runOnMount: false,
  });

 const signUpUser = () => {
    ...some requests to firebase
  };

  const handleSumbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
  };
```

Now I am trying to test this logic.

```
it('does things', async () => {
    const { container, getByTestId } = render(<Component/>);
    const form = getByTestId('form');
    
    fireEvent.submit(form);

    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

And I'm getting this error Warning: `An update to Component inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)` and it is pointing to `setError` and `setLoading` inside my hook. How to go about fixing it and testing this functionality?

Comment: What that is saying is that the component is running an update that has not finished, I would suggest to wrap the fireEvent.submit(form) inside the act helper

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but the error still here and points at setLoading and setError...

Comment: @Person What changes happen in the UI once the `fetchData` inside the `handleSumbit` completes? You should wait for those changes to happen before the snapshot assertion.